# New kind of ads is sliding on the right side of screen on each and every site

Tags: google-adsense, advertising

Some kind of ads is showing on stackexchange.com also.. Which company is providing is it google. or is it affecting me only...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0o3nE.png

Comment: Just to confirm: did you see them actually move away, or were they just not there to begin with?

Comment: When Page is scrolled it will move away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm getting the feeling you may have some sort of AdWare installed on your computer. This is almost certainly true if the ads show on every site you visit. I just visited the Starbucks website that you had in your screenshot, and I didn't get any ads at all.

I suggest running some type on anti-virus/anti-malware scan on your computer.

Malwarebytes Anti-Malware is a good program to use. You can find the free version here: http://www.malwarebytes.org/products/malwarebytes_free